# AES encrypt in Cryptojs, decrypt in Pycrypto

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, aes, pycrypto

I've tried md5 and sha256 when converting key to 16 bit but after encrypting, the result doesnt work if I'm going to validate it via third party decryptor https://www.browserling.com/tools/aes-decrypt

My goal is to decrypt the js version using python.

Added another link for js version. 
https://jsfiddle.net/korvacs/4obfkxm7/17/

Python code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
import hashlib
from base64 import b64encode

key = "lazydog".encode("utf-8")
key = hashlib.sha256(key).digest()

iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
msg = iv + cipher.encrypt('Attack at dawn')

print(b64encode(msg).decode('utf-8'))
```

Can someone help me? I'm not really good in encryptions.

Comment: Hash algorithm `md5` and `sha256` are designed in a way that they can't be used give back the plane text. They can't be decrypted.

Comment: So how do I convert my key into 16 bit or let's say what hash does aes js version use?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Decrypt "lazydog" text or "Attack at dawn"? AES cannot just work with passwords, the link you provided gives no information about how they convert passwords to AES keys

Comment: "lazydog" is the key/password/passphrase. I want to decrypt the "Attack at dawn" from its results. About the information you can check this link. https://jsfiddle.net/korvacs/4obfkxm7/17/

Comment: It will be much simpler if you don't use string as key in CryptoJS. Can you change your JS code?

Comment: Which part @Zergatul? the js version is perfectly working.

Comment: It is working, but it simulates openssl `EVP_BytesToKey` function, which is quite complicated, and it was recently changed. If I change both js and python code and make them working, will this be good for you?

Comment: @Zergatul no problem, thanks in advance. Currently debugging also the python version

Comment: From [the docs](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/): *For the key, when you pass a string, it's treated as a passphrase and used to derive an actual key and IV. Or you can pass a WordArray that represents the actual key. If you pass the actual key, you must also pass the actual IV.* So I would advise to first get it working with hard-coded keys, then figure out how to use PBKDF2 in a compatible way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using PBKDF2 to generate IV and key. This is good practice. We don't need to transfer IV:

Javascript:

```js
let password = "lazydog";
let salt = "salt";
let iterations = 128;
let bytes = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, salt, { keySize: 48, iterations: iterations });
let iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(bytes.toString().slice(0, 32));
let key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(bytes.toString().slice(32, 96));

let ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Attack at dawn", key, { iv: iv });
console.log(ciphertext.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script>
```

Python:

```
from base64 import b64decode
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2 

data = b64decode("ibirgCQu8TwtJOaKKtMLxw==")

bytes = PBKDF2("lazydog".encode("utf-8"), "salt".encode("utf-8"), 48, 128)
iv = bytes[0:16]
key = bytes[16:48]
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
text = cipher.decrypt(data)
text = text[:-text[-1]].decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Dude, Thank you!